# BCM4360 on MacbookPro running QubesOS - Kernel does not bind modul

Tags: debian, module

Help!

I have installed on a Qubes Standalone Debian-11 VM which is running on a MacbookPro the Broadcom-sta-dkms package.
The installation does NOT indicate any errors.

**lsmod shows the *wl* module:**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `sudo lsmod|grep wl`
wl                   6471680  0
cfg80211              983040  1 wl

**The *wl.ko* module is present:**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `sudo find / -name wl.ko -print`
*/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/5.10.0-21-amd64/x86_64/module/wl.ko

find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied

/usr/lib/modules/5.10.0-21-amd64/updates/dkms/wl.ko*

**I have added the module to /etc/modules**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `cat /etc/modules`
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
**wl**

**rfkill shows NOTHING!**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `sudo rfkill list all`

**inxi -n shows NO driver:**
user@sys-wifi:~$ **sudo inxi -n**
Network:   Device-1: Intel 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI type: network bridge driver: **N/A**
Device-2: Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: **N/A**
IF-ID-1: eth0 state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 00:16:3e:5e:6c:00

**nmcli does NOT show any wireless interface:**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `sudo nmcli`
eth0: connected to VM uplink eth0
"eth0"
ethernet (vif), 00:16:3E:5E:6C:00, hw, mtu 1500
ip4 default
inet4 10.137.0.21/32
route4 10.138.8.117/32
route4 0.0.0.0/0
inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe5e:6c00/64
route6 fe80::/64

lo: unmanaged
"lo"
loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
servers: 10.139.1.1 10.139.1.2
interface: eth0

Use "nmcli device show" to get complete information about known devices and
"nmcli connection show" to get an overview on active connection profiles.

Consult nmcli(1) and nmcli-examples(7) manual pages for complete usage details.

**dmesg shows no errors:**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `sudo dmesg|grep wl`

**The output of lshw**
user@sys-wifi:~$ sudo `lshw -C network`
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
physical id: 6
bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
version: 03
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:f2210000-f2217fff memory:f2000000-f21fffff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
physical id: 1
logical name: eth0
serial: 00:16:3e:5e:6c:00
capabilities: ethernet physical
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vif driverversion=5.10.0-21-amd64 ip=10.137.0.21 link=yes multicast=yes

**lspci shown the wifi adapter and the assigned module **wl** but NO kernel module is in use**
user@sys-wifi:~$ `sudo lspci -k`
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Qemu virtual machine
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Qemu virtual machine
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Qemu virtual machine
Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
Kernel modules: ata_piix, ata_generic
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Qemu virtual machine
Kernel modules: i2c_piix4
00:02.0 Unassigned class [ff80]: XenSource, Inc. Xen Platform Device (rev 01)
Subsystem: XenSource, Inc. Xen Platform Device
Kernel driver in use: xen-platform-pci
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (rev 02)
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. Device 1100
Kernel driver in use: bochs-drm
Kernel modules: bochs_drm
00:04.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 10)
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU Virtual Machine
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:06.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
Kernel modules: bcma, **wl**
user@sys-wifi:~$

Can anyone say anything about this puzzle?
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with [this](https://forum.qubes-os.org/t/hcl-apple-macbook-pro-11-1/15944/15) solution.

Namely:

---

Assumption:
Some internet connection, either wired or wireless using a dongle (sys-usb)

Steps:

1. Create a new qube based on the fedora-36 template

- Open Qube Manager → New qube

```
[Basic] Name and label: sys-wl
[Basic] Type: StandaloneVM (fully persistent)
[Basic] Template: fedora-36 (default)
[Basic] Networking: sys-net (you need somebody to connect you)
[Basic] Enable “Launch settings after creation”
[Advanced] Enable "Provides network access to other qubes"
[Advanced] Leave everything else as it is preconfigured
```

- After Creation the [Dom0] Settings window for sys-wl pops up

```
[Basic] Leave everything else as it is preconfigured
[Advanced] Disable “Include in memory balancing”
[Advanced] Kernel->Kernel: (provided by qube) → alternatively: (dom0): qvm-prefs sys-wl kernel ‘’
[Advanced] Virtualization->Mode: HVM
```

2. Install broadcom-wl

```
Open a terminal
sys-wl: Terminal
Based on the information by balko here
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rpmfusion-free
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rpmfusion-free-updates
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rpmfusion-nonfree
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo dnf install broadcom-wl
```

3. Blacklist unwanted modules

```
[user@sys-wl ~]$ sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist b43
blacklist bcma
```

4. Prepare settings for sys-wl prior to restart

```
Open Qube Manager
sys-wl->Settings
[Basic] Net qube: (none)(current)
[Basic] Leave everything else as it is already configured
```

5. Detach BCM4350 in case that it is attached to any VM (in my case it was attached per default to sys-net)

- Shutdown the VM (my case: sys-net) to which the bcm4360 card has been assigned.
- Open Qube Manager → sys-net → Settings → Devices → click in the right window frame on “Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter”, and move ( < ) it to the left one → OK

6. Attach BCM4360 to the newly created sys-wl with the “magic” options

- Shutdown the newly created sys-wl
- Find out the BDF of your device

```
(dom0) qvm-pci
BACKEND:DEVID DESCRIPTION USED BY
…
dom0:02_00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
…
```

- Now: The magic one step. BEING WELL AWARE OF side channel attacks based on this description (How to use PCI devices | Qubes OS) attach the device to sys-wl:

```
(dom0) sudo qvm-pci a sys-bcm4360 dom0:02_00.0 --persistent -o no-strict-reset=true -o permissive=true

Show the changes:
(dom0) qvm-pci
BACKEND:DEVID DESCRIPTION USED BY
…
dom0:02_00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter sys-bcm4360 (no-strict-reset=true, permissive=true)
…
```

7. Reboot the whole system

- After you got your system up and running again, the Network Manager icon will be shown on the right part of the taskbar, and available networks will be shown, and you will be able to establish a wireless connection.